# How to display available cars

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem with sql query. I would like to display a list of available cars for rent (not occupied), for example if my car has been rented for 3 days from 1.06 to 3.06 and if display available cars I will choose from datetimepicker1 date from 1.06 and datetimepicker2 date to 3.06 it does not show me this car to borrow (OK) but if i shift the date from datetimepicker to 4.06 or higher it auto is already on loan although it is loaned to 3.06.

my sql query:

```
string query = @"SELECT C.* FROM Auta C WHERE C.Auto_Id NOT IN (SELECT Auto_Id FROM Rezerwacje R WHERE ((@data1 >= R.DataFrom) AND (@data1 <= R.DataTo) AND (@data2 >= DataFrom) AND (@data2 <= DataTo)))";
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you get a date range in the form of start date (@date1) and end date (@data2)  Right?

You want to pick rows where the DateFrom and DateTo don't "overlap" this range.

So it could be the case that the start date is somewhere in the range.

```
 @date1 BETWEEN  R.DataFrom AND R.DataTo
```

it could also be where the end date is between those ranges

```
 @date2 BETWEEN  R.DataFrom AND R.DataTo
```

or that start is before and end is after

```
@date1 < R.DataFrom AND  @date2 > R.DateTo
```

The final case (both are inside is covered by one of the first two.  Now just select and exclude

```
 SELECT *
 FROM whatever 
 WHERE NOT
   (
     (@date1 BETWEEN  R.DataFrom AND R.DataTo)
     OR
     (@date2 BETWEEN  R.DataFrom AND R.DataTo)
     OR
     (@date1 < R.DataFrom AND  @date2 > R.DateTo)
   )
```

Simple right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is just the order of comparisons. Try this:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Auta C
WHERE C.Auto_Id NOT IN
    (SELECT 
     Auto_Id 
     FROM Rezerwacje R
     WHERE (R.DataFrom >= @data1 
     and R.DataFrom <= @data2)
     OR  (R.DataTo >= @data1
     and R.DataTo <= @data2));
```

Comment: Not the order of the operators, but of the dates

Comment: In the first comparison, it asks that R.DataFrom be smaller than date1, and should be larger.

Comment: Ok, but look at my answer -- as you can see that what they want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.* FROM Auta C WHERE C.Auto_Id NOT IN
(SELECT Auto_Id 
FROM Rezerwacje R 
WHERE @data1 <= DataTo AND @data2 >= R.DataFrom)
```

Answer of @Hogan has a good point, but it is a bit complicated and without the subselect it is rather misleading anyway so I made my own version.

Comment: This fails if `@data2` is between DataTo and DataFrom

Comment: @Hogan if @data2 is between DataFrom and DataTo then `@data2 >= R.DataFrom` is obviously true. As @data1 <= @data2 and @data2 <= DataTo (it is between, remember?) `@data1 <= DataTo` is true either. Those intervals are correctly evaluated as overlapping and the car is excluded from the result.